# How to extract signature from web3.eth.sign or web3.personal.sign

Tags: web3js, signature, react, typescript

In React Typescript (.tsx file), I'm trying to use `web3.eth.sign` to validate an account. The signature is being generated properly, but I can't seem to get the signature out of the callback function.

The following code is inside a functional component:

```
const [signature, setSignature] = useState<string>('')

function Sign() {
   const web3 = window.web3

   web3.personal.sign(
      nonce,
      accountId,
      function(err: any, signed: string) {
         if (!err) {
            console.log(`${signed}`)
            setSignature(signed) 
            console.log(`Signature = ${signature}`)
         }
   })
}

Sign()
// some other code that uses signature variable
```

`signed` is printing a valid signature, but `signature` is not being set. This is a big problem. For the rest of my code to work I need to get the `signed` variable and set it to an external `signature` variable where I can pass it to other functions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**One solution:** Instead of UseState, put your `signature` code inside the anonymous function.

Instead of

```
const [signature, setSignature] = useState<string>('')

function Sign() {
   const web3 = window.web3

   web3.personal.sign(
      nonce,
      accountId,
      function(err: any, signed: string) {
         if (!err) {
            console.log(`${signed}`)
            setSignature(signed) 
            console.log(`Signature = ${signature}`)
         }
   })
}

Sign()
// some other code that uses signature variable
```

Do this:

```
function Sign() {
   const web3 = window.web3

   web3.personal.sign(
      nonce,
      accountId,
      function(err: any, signed: string) {
         if (!err) {
            console.log(`${signed}`)
            // some other code that uses signature variable, now denoted as signed
         }
   })
}

Sign()
```

It doesn't exactly solve the problem, but it worked for my use case and might work for yours if you're having a similar issue.

Comment: with which version of web3.js is this working? I am using (this)[https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js] and I get `Error: Returned error: Method not found
    at Object.ErrorResponse (errors.js:28)
    at index.js:303
    at XMLHttpRequest.i.onreadystatechange (index.js:98)`

Answer (score 0):

This is not about web3, it's about `ReactJS`. The state change performed by `setSignature` is not immediately reflected, but it will be in the next render cycle.

In React, state updates are typically batched for performance reasons, meaning that multiple state updates that occur within the same event loop cycle are grouped together and applied at once. Additionally, updates to state are not guaranteed to be immediate, as they may be queued and applied at a later time.